# HTTPSimpleServer - How to close/terminate it?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I recently learned I could run a server with this command:

```
sudo python -m HTTPSimpleServer
```

**My question: how do I terminate this server when done with it?**

Comment: Side note: you don't have to be root to run it (ie. no `sudo` required), as it binds to non-privileged port by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type Control-C.  Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the HttpServer class in [this servlet module](http://code.google.com/p/verse-quiz/source/browse/trunk/servlet.py) for a modification that allows the server to be quit. If the handler raises a SystemExit exception, the server will break from its serving.

---

```
class HttpServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, http.server.HTTPServer):

    """Create a server with specified address and handler.

    A generic web server can be instantiated with this class. It will listen
    on the address given to its constructor and will use the handler class
    to process all incoming traffic. Running a server is greatly simplified."""

    # We should not be binding to an
    # address that is already in use.
    allow_reuse_address = False

    @classmethod
    def main(cls, RequestHandlerClass, port=80):
        """Start server with handler on given port.

        This static method provides an easy way to start, run, and exit
        a HttpServer instance. The server will be executed if possible,
        and the computer's web browser will be directed to the address."""
        try:
            server = cls(('', port), RequestHandlerClass)
            active = True
        except socket.error:
            active = False
        else:
            addr, port = server.socket.getsockname()
            print('Serving HTTP on', addr, 'port', port, '...')
        finally:
            port = '' if port == 80 else ':' + str(port)
            addr = 'http://localhost' + port + '/'
            webbrowser.open(addr)
        if active:
            try:
                server.serve_forever()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print('Keyboard interrupt received: EXITING')
            finally:
                server.server_close()

    def handle_error(self, request, client_address):
        """Process exceptions raised by the RequestHandlerClass.

        Overriding this method is necessary for two different reasons:
        (1) SystemExit exceptions are incorrectly caught otherwise and
        (2) Socket errors should be silently passed in the server code"""
        klass, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
        if klass is SystemExit:
            self.__exit = value
            self._BaseServer__serving = None
        elif issubclass(klass, socket.error):
            pass
        else:
            super().handle_error(request, client_address)

    def serve_forever(self, poll_interval=0.5):
        """Handle all incoming client requests forever.

        This method has been overridden so that SystemExit exceptions
        raised in the RequestHandlerClass can be re-raised after being
        caught in the handle_error method above. This allows servlet
        code to terminate server execution if so desired or required."""
        super().serve_forever(poll_interval)
        if self._BaseServer__serving is None:
            raise self.__exit
```